# Responsive Chart.js Canvas barplot height?

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js, height, bar-chart

I have having difficulties setting the height of my Chart.js barplot correctly (see screenshot). The

```
responsive:true,
maintainAspectRatio: false,
```

does not seem to be taken into account here. I am expecting to have the plot height to take 100% of the box.

Could anyone advice, as I scanned around, and didn't really found much.

[image]

```html
<div class="col-md-4" style="flex-direction: inherit">
  <div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
      <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
      <h3 class="box-title">dataset growth</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="boby" class="box-body">
      <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative">
        <div class="chart">
          <canvas id="barChart" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- page script -->
<script>
  var numberWithCommas = function(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  };

  var dataHsap = [395, 2829, 6498];
  var dataAtha = [0, 0, 1272];
  var dates = ["2015", "2018", "2020"];

  var bar_ctx = document.getElementById('barChart');
  var boby = document.getElementById('boby');
  var data = {
    labels: dates,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Human',
        data: dataHsap,
        backgroundColor: "#3c8dbc",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "#77b2d4",
        hoverBorderWidth: 0
      },
      {
        label: 'Thaliana',
        data: dataAtha,
        backgroundColor: "#00a65a",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "#00cc70",
        hoverBorderWidth: 0
      },
    ]
  };

  var options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    animation: {
      duration: 10,
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'label',
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ": " + numberWithCommas(tooltipItem.yLabel);
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          callback: function(value) {
            return numberWithCommas(value);
          },
        },
      }],
    },
    legend: {
      display: true
    }
  };

  var bar_chart = new Chart(bar_ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: options
  });
</script>
<div class="col-md-4" style="flex-direction: inherit">
  <div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
      <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
      <h3 class="box-title">ReMap dataset growth</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="boby" class="box-body">
      <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative">
        <div class="chart">
          <canvas id="barChart" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- page script -->
<script>
  var numberWithCommas = function(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  };

  var dataHsap = [395, 2829, 6498];
  var dataAtha = [0, 0, 1272];
  var dates = ["2015", "2018", "2020"];

  var bar_ctx = document.getElementById('barChart');
  var boby = document.getElementById('boby');
  var data = {
    labels: dates,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Human',
        data: dataHsap,
        backgroundColor: "#3c8dbc",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "#77b2d4",
        hoverBorderWidth: 0
      },
      {
        label: 'Thaliana',
        data: dataAtha,
        backgroundColor: "#00a65a",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "#00cc70",
        hoverBorderWidth: 0
      },
    ]
  };

  var options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    animation: {
      duration: 10,
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'label',
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ": " + numberWithCommas(tooltipItem.yLabel);
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          callback: function(value) {
            return numberWithCommas(value);
          },
        },
      }],
    },
    legend: {
      display: true
    }
  };

  var bar_chart = new Chart(bar_ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: options
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `responsive:true, maintainAspectRatio: true,`? What do you want to achieve, (how) should it scale or should it have a specific width/height?

Comment: Well I would like the plot to scale to the box, and it doesn't.

Comment: Removing both lines "responsive:true, maintainAspectRatio: true," seems to improve the scaling issue. Not perfect, as the aspect ratio maintained, the plot remains scared

Comment: `responsive` & `maintainAspectRatio` are `true` by default, removing shouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your chart doesn't know how big it should be. You should add a height-property to the div that contains your canvas.

```
<div class="chart" style="height: 300px">
  <canvas id="barChart" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I hope this is what you want. I'm still not sure what you want, how the chart/canvas/divs should scale in both dimensions.